# Unable to send emails using Outlook SMTP accounts

Tags: php

When I send emails using outlook smtp i get following error

> The server response was: 554 5.2.0
>   STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied;
>   Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message
>   Cannot submit message. 16.55847:69000000,
>   17.43559:0000000060010000000000000000000000000000, 20.521"

I have no problem with other smtp servers.

Comment: Can you please provide some code where you have attempted to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It relates to that [issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/livemail-email/suddenly-cant-send-emails/8e465633-dfa4-4b4b-994a-bac86cffd995)

> This applies to all email clients using smtp server to send email.
> Sometime near the beginning of July, there was a change that
> disallowed you using a return email address that is not in your list
> of verified email aliases or connected accounts. In other words, you
> can't change the "From" field in emails you send to an anonymous email
> address.

So to send email from outlook 365 you need add alias email to list of verified emails.